# Squarespace - different background image on mobile? Using a Cover Page with Mission template

Tags: css, squarespace

My wife is using a cover page temporarily for her site - we want a different background image used on mobile than on desktop. I am a complete neophyte however have injected CSS through the Advanced settings tab for the cover page and have inserted the following:

```
    <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
         body {
              background-image:url('http://s30.postimg.org/kqqdomkep/Ivy_Row_Icon_BACKGROUND_v2.jpg');
         }
    }
    </style>
```

and it does not work. What am I doing wrong? Any help someone can provide would be greatly appreciate.

I can provide the website URL if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `640x1136px` background image for screens narrower than `480px` without resizing the background. Also, your image features a large white space at the top. I think the image loads but you are only seeing the top of the image, drawing the false conclusion it doesn't load.

This should display the image on small devices:

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background: 
      white
      url('http://s30.postimg.org/kqqdomkep/Ivy_Row_Icon_BACKGROUND_v2.jpg')
      no-repeat 
      center 
      /contain;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

The key is the `/contain` part of the `background` shorthand, which could also be written separately as `background-size: contain;`
Other possible values include:

- `cover` (image gets cropped but covers the element),
- *`Length`* (in `px`, `em`, `rem`, `vw`, `cm`, `in` etc...),
- `auto` ( original size - also default - what you see now),
- `initial` (reset to initial state)
- `inherit` (apply property of parent)

Comment: Hi there. This worked like a charm. Though I believe the Squarespace Cover Page template "overwrites" everything and puts it as a white background. I wonder if there is a way to overwrite that? See: www.ivyrowdesign.com

Comment: Oops, and I also meant to say THANKS!

Comment: `div.sqs-slide { background: transparent;}` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks again! That worked. My wife now calls me her "IT-guy". Please keep my secret.